# Sharepoint not getting current user NetworkCredential from active directory

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

we have strange problem, we have single signon and we are trying to fetch unread email count from Exchange ews webservice, the problem is it always gets same count for all user which is actually for server user.

```
'it should now get for current user who requested the page 
'but its always for server user where sharepoint is installed
Public Sub GetUnreadEmailCount()
    Dim errormsg As String = String.Empty
    Dim UnreadCount As Integer = 0
    Dim esb As New ExchangeServiceBinding

    Try
        esb.RequestServerVersionValue = New RequestServerVersion
        esb.RequestServerVersionValue.Version = ExchangeVersionType.Exchange2007_SP1
        esb.UseDefaultCredentials = True
        esb.Url = Domain + "/EWS/Exchange.asmx"

        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf CertificateValidationCallBack)


        Dim biArray(1) As BaseFolderIdType
        Dim dfFolder As New DistinguishedFolderIdType
        dfFolder.Id = DistinguishedFolderIdNameType.inbox
        biArray(0) = dfFolder
        Dim geGetFolder As New GetFolderType
        geGetFolder.FolderIds = biArray
        geGetFolder.FolderShape = New FolderResponseShapeType
        geGetFolder.FolderShape.BaseShape = DefaultShapeNamesType.AllProperties
        Dim gfResponse As GetFolderResponseType = esb.GetFolder(geGetFolder)

        Dim rmta As ResponseMessageType() = gfResponse.ResponseMessages.Items
        Dim rmt As FolderInfoResponseMessageType = DirectCast(rmta(0), FolderInfoResponseMessageType)
        If rmt.ResponseClass = ResponseClassType.Success Then
            Dim folder As FolderType = DirectCast(rmt.Folders(0), FolderType)
            UnreadCount = folder.UnreadCount

        End If

        Label1.Text = vbCrLf + "Unread email count : " + UnreadCount.ToString
        ' Return UnreadCount
    Catch ex As Exception
        If Not ex.Message Is Nothing Then errormsg = ex.Message
        Try
            If Not ex.InnerException.Message Is Nothing Then errormsg = errormsg + " : " + ex.InnerException.Message
        Catch e As Exception

        End Try
    Finally
        If esb IsNot Nothing Then esb.Dispose() : esb = Nothing
        If Not errormsg = String.Empty Then
            Label1.Text = vbCrLf + "Error : " + errormsg
        End If
    End Try

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were actually having the same problem, although we were not using single sign on. So I'm not sure this is exactly what you are experiencing.

The problem is that you can not have a user on **Machine A** give their credentials to **Machine B** (SharePoint?) and then have **Machine B** send those credentials on to **Machine C**

It's referred to as the "Double Hop" problem and is a security feature, however I'm not really into the technical side of it. Our solution was to use Kerberos.

I hope this helps you, if not, that it helps you rule out this specific issue :)

Comment: can you guide me how to setup kerberos ?

Answer (score 0):

Your server side code is running as the AppPool's identity, which is your sharepoint service account. I'm assuming that's what you mean by 'the server user.'

```
esb.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

will use the creds of the context. I'm not sure of what's available in the EWS services, so if you can use a higher-privileged account and get based on the user coming in, i.e., HttpContext.Current.User.Identity as a parameter, then that may be the best way.

You could authenticate via javascript directly to the EWS services, skipping server-side code altogether, and write something that consumes & displays the server stuff as you need it.

You'd need to find a way to auth the user directly to the EWS services. Double-hop is an issue with NTLM, as your NTLM ticket is only valid for the first hop. Kerberos fixes that, but you still need to impersonate.

Comment: Thank allot, is it possible to call EWS services through java-script ? if yes then that will be really awesome as it will increase performance also, else try Kerberos and let you know