# Facing Double Hop should we use Exchange Impersonation or Kerberos delegation

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, active-directory, exchange-server

We have Sharepoint 2010 environment with AD windows authenticated users, we want to display user's unread inbox email count from exchange server 2007, but unfortunately we are facing double hop as i asked this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8892652/sharepoint-not-getting-current-user-networkcredential-from-active-directory), after doing a bit more research it seems we have only two solutions

**1- Use Exchange Impersonation:**

My Concern : Our user have highly classified information in their inbox, so with Exchange Impersonation can we programmers will become a security risk ? or is impersonation occurs for only currently logged in windows authenticated user.....to put it simply, Is Exchange impersonation secure enough for my case ?

**2- Use Kerberos Delegation :**

I know its the right way but we could not configure it, Can anyone help me by providing simple step by step guide for Kerberos delegation setup for my case, as we do every right but double hop still occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delegation seems like the cleaner solution here. You'd need to get your Exchange admins to setup an Alternate Service Account (ASA) for Exchange to use so that you can use Kerb AuthN with it. From there, you'd need to configure the Sharepoint service accounts to delegate to the http/foo.domain.com SPN on the ASA.

Comment: Thanks allot, our system administrators are pretty lazy after informing them as u mention, they  said give us step by step guide, u seems to know all this, can you please inform step by step... i will be really thankful to you..

Comment: Yes, done allot of research but i never setup Active directory or Exchange server  where i followed steps as given here [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2009/10/20/configuring-kerberos-authentication-in-sharepoint-2010-part-1.aspx), but nothing seems to work.